# Microsoft.ML can't save model because of an illegal path?

Tags: c#, machine-learning, microsoft.ml

Have been playing around with machine learning as of late, made a basic machine learning algorithm. It was working perfectly and then I broke something and now it refuses to save the model.

here's the code:

```
        private static string MODEL_FILEPATH = @"MLModel.zip";
    // Create MLContext to be shared across the model creation workflow objects 
    // Set a random seed for repeatable/deterministic results across multiple trainings.
    private static MLContext mlContext = new MLContext(seed: 1);

    public static void CreateModel()
    {
        // Load Data
        IDataView trainingDataView = mlContext.Data.LoadFromTextFile<ModelInput>(
                                        path: TRAIN_DATA_FILEPATH,
                                        hasHeader: true,
                                        separatorChar: ',',
                                        allowQuoting: true,
                                        allowSparse: false);

        // Build training pipeline
        IEstimator<ITransformer> trainingPipeline = BuildTrainingPipeline(mlContext);

        // Evaluate quality of Model
        //Evaluate(mlContext, trainingDataView, trainingPipeline);

        // Train Model
        ITransformer mlModel = TrainModel(mlContext, trainingDataView, trainingPipeline);

        // Save model
        SaveModel(mlContext, mlModel, MODEL_FILEPATH, trainingDataView.Schema);
    }
    private static void SaveModel(MLContext mlContext, ITransformer mlModel, string 
modelRelativePath, DataViewSchema modelInputSchema)
    {

        try
        {
            mlContext.Model.Save(mlModel, null, (GetAbsolutePath(modelRelativePath)));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString() + "\n" + e.Message + ": " + GetAbsolutePath(modelRelativePath));
        }

    }
```

this code was automatically generated, I just removed the comment, added the try catch and specified the model path.

here's the exception:

```
  > Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in mscorlib.dll
   System.ArgumentException: The path is not of a legal form.
   at System.IO.Path.NewNormalizePath(String path, Int32 maxPathLength, Boolean expandShortPaths)
   at System.IO.Path.NormalizePath(String path, Boolean fullCheck, Int32 maxPathLength, Boolean 
   expandShortPaths)
   at System.IO.Path.GetFullPathInternal(String path)
   at System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(String path)
   at System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.GetFullPathWithAssert(String fileName)
   at System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(String fileName)
   at Microsoft.ML.RepositoryWriter.CreateNew(Stream stream, IExceptionContext ectx, Boolean 
   useFileSystem)
   at Microsoft.ML.ModelOperationsCatalog.Save(ITransformer model, DataViewSchema inputSchema, Stream 
   stream)
   at Microsoft.ML.ModelOperationsCatalog.Save(ITransformer model, DataViewSchema inputSchema, String 
   filePath)
   at MachineLearningTest.ModelBuilder.SaveModel(MLContext mlContext, ITransformer mlModel, String 
   modelRelativePath, DataViewSchema modelInputSchema) in 
   C:\Users\Michael\Source\Repos\new\MachineLearingTest\ModelBuilder.cs:line 83
   The path is not of a legal form.: 
   C:\Users\Michael\Source\Repos\new\MachineLearingTest\bin\x64\Debug\MLModel.zip
```

[and this is the file which is supposed to contain the model(it is empty)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHCwu.png)

Comment: Can you please debug and check the value of this? `typeof(ModelSaveContext).Assembly.Location` Please don't ask why for now. It is related.

Comment: Ok here is why. The error has nothing to do with your model path (for which a stream is already created successfully), but with this line inside `Microsoft.ML.Core.RepositoryWriter` internal abstract class: `FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(typeof(RepositoryWriter).Assembly.Location);`

Comment: typeof(ModelSaveContext).Assembly.Location is just an empty string
https://imgur.com/zvieDxX

Comment: so how should I go about fixing that? that's such a weird error I've never come across something like that

Comment: Can you check `typeof(ModelSaveContext).Assembly.CodeBase`? The documentation for Assembly.Location says: " If the assembly is loaded from a byte array, such as when using the Load(Byte[]) method overload, the value returned is an empty string (""). "

Comment: typeof(ModelSaveContext).Assembly.CodeBase = "file:///C:/Users/Michael/Source/Repos/new/MachineLearingTest/bin/x64/Debug/MachineLearningTest.exe"

Comment: Did you do any changes recently, like upgrading ML package, or changing it's location, anything? I think this should go to the ML team as a ticket, but first we need to be sure.

Comment: Oh this is weird? ModelSaveContext is not your class, is it?

Comment: Damn. Look at CodeBase documentation: If the assembly was loaded as a byte array, using an overload of the Load method that takes an array of bytes, this property returns the location of the caller of the method, not the location of the loaded assembly.

Comment: Did you do any dynamic assembly loading?

Comment: I'm not sure what that means

Comment: I did update the ML package recently

Comment: Are you using 1.4.0? or the new preview?

Comment: I'm using 1.5preview2

Comment: These problems are expected with preview versions, so if you are not using anything new from 1.5 preview 2, please go back to 1.4 stable, and you should open an issue [here](https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/issues)